# Navigator over multiple highchart to select range

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am trying to create a single drag navigator over multiple highchart to highlight chart between ranges. like below attachment. [image]

Can someone please let me know how can I do this? I explored highchart but could not find appropriate options to create this. Are there any other options?

Here is what I have tried:

```js
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'zoom', function(proceed, event) {
    var navMin = event.xAxis[0].min,
      navMax = event.xAxis[0].max;

    H.each(Highcharts.charts, function(chart) {
      if (chart.userOptions.chart.customNavigator) {
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(navMin, navMax);
      }
    });
  });
}(Highcharts));

$.getJSON('https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-c.json', function(data) {
  var newMin = data[0][0],
    newMax = data[data.length - 1][0];

  Highcharts.stockChart('container-main', {
    chart: {
      customNavigator: true,
      type: 'area',
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },
    navigator: {
      enabled: false
    },
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
  },
    xAxis: {
      labels:{
        enabled:false
      },
      minorTickLength:0,
      minorTicks:false,
      tickLength:0
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'AAPL',
      data: data,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
      }
    }]
  });
  Highcharts.stockChart('container-main1', {
    chart: {
      customNavigator: true,
      type: 'area',
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },
    navigator: {
      enabled: false
    },
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
  },
    xAxis: {
      labels:{
        enabled:false
      },
      minorTickLength:0,
      minorTicks:false,
      tickLength:0
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'AAPL',
      data: data,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
      }
    }]
  });
    Highcharts.stockChart('container-main2', {
    chart: {
      customNavigator: true,
      type: 'area',
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1
    },
    navigator: {
      enabled: false
    },
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
  },
    xAxis: {
      labels:{
        enabled:false
      },
      minorTickLength:0,
      minorTicks:false,
      tickLength:0
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'AAPL',
      data: data,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2
      }
    }]
  });

  Highcharts.stockChart('container-navigator', {
    chart: {
      height: 600,
      zoomType: 'x',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    navigator: {
      enabled: true,
      height:540,
      opposite:true,
      maskInside:false
    },
    rangeSelector: {
      enabled: true
    },
    scrollbar: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      min: newMin,
      max: newMax,
      labels:{
        enabled:false
      },
      minorTickLength:0,
      minorTicks:false,
      tickLength:0
    },
    yAxis: {
      visible: false
    },
     series: []
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
}
#container-navigator{ position:absolute; top:0; width:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>


<div id="container-main" style="height: 200px; min-width:200px"></div>
<div id="container-main1" style="height: 200px; min-width:200px"></div>
<div id="container-main2" style="height: 200px; min-width:200px"></div>
<div id="container-navigator"></div>
```

also attached jsFiddle what I have tried: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/uan8epvr/)

I am also open to any other library achieving this type of result.

Comment: Your solution look's nice, what do you want to add, where are you stack?

Comment: as I add overlay above the chart so tooltip and other crosshair of highchart wont perform that's why I am stuck over their @SebastianHajdus

Answer (score 0):

In the current solution you can create a timeline using SVGRenderer as below I show how I rendered the button. For visibility, I added them to the container navigator.

```
   chart: {
      events: {
        load: function() {
          const chart = this;
          chart.renderer.button('Change visible time range', 100, 50)
            .attr({
              zIndex: 40,
            })
            .on('click', function() {
              chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(navMin, navMax))
            })
            .add()
        }
      }
    }
```

In your solution with the navigator stretched to full height, the navigator covers all the charts and the tooltip cannot be shown that way, it's under the navigator container.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u6gjdzsn/2/

Comment: Another approach, might be to render a mask that corresponds a navigator and plug into it the setExtremes.

API References that you can use to build a custom navigator:

[Highcharts.SVGRenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer),
[xAxis.plotBands](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.plotBands),
[chart.plotShadow](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.plotShadow).